# how to export dynamic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have directories

```
/main
  index.js
  other
  other1
  other2
  /data
    index.js
    type1.js
    type2.js
```

In top index.js

```
export * from './other';
export * from './other1';
export * from './other2';
export * from './data';
```

in type1.js

```
export const Q => <div>hi</div>
```

in type2.js

```
export const Q => <div>how are u?</div>
```

how create dynamic export in data/index.js like

```
cont data = () => {
  if (condition){
    return require('./type1.js');
  }else {
    return require('./type2.js');
  }
}

export default data;
```